# how to save/load Dictionary from a sharedObject

Tags: actionscript-3

I have 2 questions directed to Dictionary

1st :
Im having a problem with saving data from Dictionary / loading data to Dictionary and i cant see why this isnt working.What am i doing wrong here???

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.utils.Dictionary;
import flash.net.SharedObject;

public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    private var _box:Dictionary = new Dictionary  ;
    private var _change:Dictionary = new Dictionary  ;
    private var _loadingItems:Dictionary = new Dictionary  ;

    private var sData:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("octopod_4");

    public function Main()
    {
        if (sData.data.myStorage == undefined)
        {
            trace("1st time this game");
            for (var i:int = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                var myImage_mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
                _box[i] = myImage_mc;
                if ( i > 1 )
                {
                    _change[myImage_mc] = _box[i - 2];
                }
            }
            sData.data.myStorage = _change;
            sData.flush();
            trace(sData.data.myStorage);


            //we trace what we have in the Dictionary
            for (var key:* in _change)
            {
                trace('_conditions[' + key.name + '] = ' + _change[key].name);
            }
            for (var key:* in _box)
            {
                trace('_box[' + key + '] = ' + _box[key].name);
            }

        }
        else if ( sData.data.myStorage != undefined )
        {
            trace("loaded before");
            _loadingItems = sData.data.myObject;
            trace("_loadingitems " + _loadingItems)
        }
    }
}
```

2nd question: how can i extract that data from **sData.data.myObject;**  and input it to 
**_loadingItems**
What i mean is that because of the error it gives me  **Error #2004: One of the parameters is invalid.**   i cant see if the data from the **sData.data.myObject;** is copied to **_loadingItems**. Is it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting MovieClips in your dictionary, and nothing extending `DisplayObject` can be saved in a shared object unless you implement `IExternalizable` for them. This is because any display object has publicly available stage reference which is dynamic, that is, the value stored in `stage` property is a pointer to a memory location. Then, when you are trying to load an object out of a shared object, the behavior by default is to set all the properties to stored values which are now invalid because Flash occupies a different set of memory addresses each time a movie is loaded, and you get your 2004. `IExternalizable` implementation overrides the default behavior with custom code, but you have to comply with certain hard restrictions when you write its implementation. So, if you want to store something in a shared object, you should devise a way to store only metadata that is somewhat static (strings, numbers, arrays are fine, but nested objects usually aren't, note that an object as a member of the array is a nested object too), and then create a set of dynamic objects (display objects of all sorts) according to retrieved metadata.